# Ext JS 6 can't right align my button xtype

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I have built a very simple login page in Ext JS 6.6, but for the life of me I can't seem to right align the login button with the end of the form fields. It just stays to the left no matter what I do.

[image: Login form]

How can I fix this problem?

The code I'm using is as follows;

```
items: {
    xtype: 'form',
    reference: 'form',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'username',
        fieldLabel: 'Username',
        allowBlank: false
    }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'password',
        inputType: 'password',
        fieldLabel: 'Password',
        allowBlank: false
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Login',
        formBind: true,
        style: {
            marginTop: '10px',
            padding: '5px 15px 5px 15px'
        },
        listeners: {
            click: 'onLoginClick'
        }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`bbar`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.form.Panel.html#cfg-bbar) config for [`form`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.form.Panel.html) component like this

```
bbar: [
  '->',//spliter to shift next component up to end of right
  { xtype: 'button', text: 'Button 1' }
]
```

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2joe)**, I have create a demo using `bbar` config.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create({
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Login View',
            border: true,
            width: 320,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: {
                xtype: 'form',
                reference: 'form',
                bodyPadding: 15,
                layout: 'vbox',
                defaults: {
                    width: '100%'
                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'username',
                    fieldLabel: 'Username',
                    allowBlank: false
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'password',
                    inputType: 'password',
                    fieldLabel: 'Password',
                    allowBlank: false
                }],
                bbar: ['->', {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Login',
                    formBind: true,
                    listeners: {
                        click: 'onLoginClick'
                    }
                }]
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey, is there any reason why the button changes from the standard blue to a light grey?

Comment: there is no specif reason depend on what theme you have used . I have used  `[Classic] Neptune Touch` so that's why color light grey

Comment: Thank you, I decided to take this option.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Nest the button inside an xtype:'container' with a layout:

   ```
   {
       xtype: 'container',
       layout: {
           type: 'vbox',
           align: 'right'
       },
       items: [{
           xtype: 'button',
           text: 'Login',
           formBind: true,
           listeners: {
               click: 'onLoginClick'
           }
       }]
   }
   ```
2. Use property "margin" on xtype 'button'.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the info, im kind of new and learning and I was wondering if there is any chance you could show me what you mean?

Comment: The extra container needs a layout, as so: `{
                    xtype: 'container',
                    layout: {
                        type: 'vbox',
                        align: 'right'
                    },
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Login',
                        formBind: true,
                        listeners: {
                            click: 'onLoginClick'
                        }
                    }]
                }`
Though personally I prefer the bbar option in the other answer

Comment: Edited the answer instead to correct it, as comments aren't great for code snippets

Answer (score 0):

place your button inside buttons configuration.It will automatically align your button to right.

```
buttons:[{
    text: 'Login',
    formBind: true,
    style: {
        marginTop: '10px',
        padding: '5px 15px 5px 15px'
    },
    listeners: {
        click: 'onLoginClick'
    }
}]
```

Comment: Hey, yeh i used that initially, but i couldnt get rid of that damn grey background

Comment: Okie then bbar option is the better one.